# Events received by client websocket as a consequence of calling builder.Prompts.text() in a bot are missing the activity payload

Tags: react-native, botframework, direct-line-botframework

## botframework Node.js [DirectLine 3.0 API / React Native Client (Android)] Events received by client websocket as a consequence of calling builder.Prompts.text() in a bot are missing the ‘data’ property (i.e. the activity payload).

**Version Information**

React Native Client (Android)

- Node.js v7.5.0
- react-native v0.41.2

Bot

- Node.js v6.3.1
- botbuilder v3.7.0

DirectLine

- API v3.0

**Description of Issue**

Events received by client websocket as a consequence of calling builder.Prompts.text() in a bot are missing the ‘data’ property (i.e. the activity payload).

Note: Subsequent events following this one will include the Symbol ‘original_event’ which includes the missing event details that would have been expected in the initial event.

Direct Line request from bot (i.e. captured from ChatConnector.authenticatedRequest()):

```
{
  json: true,
  method: “POST”,
  url: “https://state.botframework.com/v3/botstate/directline/conversations/[MY CONVERSATION ID]”,
  body: {
    from: {
      id: “MyBot@ZSXyfFggVqW”,
      name: “MyBot”
    },
    recipient: {
      id: “MyClientId”
   },
    text: “Hi Pete, please enter the code displayed in the browser page to complete the sign in process.”,
    type: “message” 
  }         
}
```

Event received by websocket:

```
{
  … // Expecting a data property at this level. Don’t confuse this with the data property in the Symbol below, which is for the previous event.
  Symbol(original_event): {
    data: "{
      "activities": [
        {
          "type": "typing",
          "id": "[MY CONVERSATION ID]|5ChLjtMKBEz",
          "timestamp": "2017-05-04T10:37:48.3923201Z",
          "channelId": "directline",
          "from": {
          "id": "MyBot",
          "name": "MyBot"
        },
        "conversation": {
          "id": "[MY CONVERSATION ID]"
        }
      }
    ]}",
    type: ”message”
  },
  timestamp: 1493894269211,
  type: “message”
}
```

Event after the one above contains:

```
{
  …
  Symbol(original_event): {
    data: "{
    "activities": [
      {
        "type": "message",
        "id": "[MY CONVERSATION ID]|0000030",
        "timestamp": "2017-05-04T10:37:49.092354Z",
        "channelId": "directline",
        "from": {
          "id": "MyBot",
          "name": "MyBot"
        },
        "conversation": {
          "id": "[MY CONVERSATION ID]"
        },
        "text": "Hi Pete, please enter the code displayed in the browser page to complete the sign in process.”
      }
    ],
    "watermark": "30"
    }",
    type: ”message”
  },
  timestamp: 1493894511787,
  type: “message”
}
```

Notes:

•   Notice that the event following the original has the data property we would have expected, contained in the Symbol “original_event”.

•   If the same conversation thread is attempted for any other channel type, the message *“Hi Pete, please enter the code displayed in the browser page to complete the sign in process”* IS shown in the chat window (i.e. Skype, Slack, Web Chat etc). It is only direct line that appears to have the issue.

•   The message in question is a proactive message triggered after a user has been authenticated and a redirect URL called. The message is required to prompt the user for a second form of authentication, in this particular case an access code.

•   If all historic message activities are requested for the above conversation, the missing message is among said activities i.e.:

https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations/[MY CONVERSATION ID]/activities?watermark=[INITIAL WATERMARK]

```
{
      "activities": [
            …
    {
      "type": "message",
      "id": "[MY CONVERSATION ID]|0000009",
      "timestamp": "2017-05-04T17:48:33.0747342Z",
      "channelId": "directline",
      "from": {
        "id": "MyBot"
      },
      "conversation": {
        "id": "[MY CONVERSATION ID]"
      },
      "text": "Hi Pete, please enter the code displayed in the browser page to complete the sign in process."
    }
…
```

Any suggestions?

**Update 05/05/2017**

Currently pursing two avenues of thought, either there is an issue with the WebSocket library bundled with React Native, or we have a general Direct Line WebSocket issue (a colleague of mine will be retesting with a native IOS client this morning to confirm one way or another).

Answer (score 0):

No longer an issue. Websocket events now appear to be coming through as expected.